# More condition in powershell and not logical return

Tags: powershell, logical-operators

I need to get driveletter for my condition, but powershell return "true" or "false" for this

```
(Get-Volume).driveletter `
  -and (get-volume).size -gt "700000000000" `
  -and (get-physicaldisk).MediaType -eq "HDD"
```

When get `(Get-Volume).driveletter` is return driveletter, when more condition return logical. Why?

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's logical operators return boolean `$true` and `$false`. While the arguments to the operators are converted their original values are not conserved.

(Some languages like JavaScript will return the pre-converted values from logical operators, but many languages do not.)

For this you would be better with a pipeline:

```
$res = Get-Volume `
   | ? { $_.driveletter -and $_.size -gt "700000000000" `
          -and (get-physicaldisk -objectid $_.ObjectId).MediaType -eq "HDD" }
```

This also avoids the issue that `(get-physicaldisk).MediaType -eq "HDD"` will be true if any disk is a HDD. Whereas I suspet you want the drive that is a HDD, has a drive letter and has sufficient size.

Comment: It's better to write out `Where-Object` (or at least to explain that `?` is shorthand syntax).

Comment: The ObjectID strings of Get-Volume and Get-PhysicalDisk are not related, You can use [gwmi and associators](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/using-wmi-to-link-a-disk-volume-to-a-physical-disk-with-powershell/) to connect them.

Comment: @richard
this work, thnx, how to add ":" to drive letter output? to use `$hdd.driveletter` in move function  


`$hdd = Get-Volume | ? { $_.driveletter -and $_.size -gt "700000000000" }  
  $hdd.driveletter  
C`

Comment: @nfeel Use string concanenation: `$hdd.driveletter + ':'` (system information APIs and their wrappers are inconsistent on this, you need to handle on a case by case basis).

Comment: @richard i try this today
`$hdd.driveletter + ':'
C:`
but `cd $hdd.driveletter + ':'` not working

Comment: @nfeel (that probably needs another question) but try `cd ($hdd.driveletter + ':')` (Personally I would use another variable for the drive letter with colon for clarity). And "it does not work" is not helpful: PowerShell would have given you an error about `argument path`.